# PsTools Cannot Connect Remotely with IP Address

Tags: cmd, remote-access, psexec

I need to grab information remotely from a few pcs using PsTools.

Currently I get all the info I need through an ethernet connection using commands like: `psinfo \\(computer name) -u User -p Password`

But I need to remotely connect and run commands through their ip addresses now. They are connected to the internet through cell connections.
Supposedly I'm supposed to use something like:

```
psexec \\(IP Address) -u (IP Address)\User -p Password cmd
```

and it should just connect, but instead I get messages like "The network path was not found" and "cannot connect to remote registry on (IP Address)"

I have already applied the registry changes required to execute commands remotely: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951016 so I have no issue there.

How should I connect to the computer? Am I using the wrong commands or syntax?

Comment: "connected to the internet through cell connections"? As in "cell phone"? Then I guess you're out of luck. Try if you can `ping` the mobile devices; this will probably fail because cellular networks normally do not support incoming traffic.

Comment: @JimmyB They are connected through Modems (using SIM cards). I can ping their IP Addresses fine, and we've been using Microsoft's Remote-Desktop application for years, PsTools just can't seem to locate them...

Comment: Are they connected via VPN?

Comment: @JimmyB Nope... They also have no firewalls up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psexec` on first run asks to accept eula... you need to add `/accepteula` param... second thing is that you need to be in `HOME` network, not `PUBLIC` one... if network is set to `PUBLIC`, `RPC` is not available.

Comment: But I've already connected to some using the ethernet connection and they worked? Do I have to input `-accepteula` every time I attempt to connect to a pc? Like this: `psexec \\(IP Address) -u (IP Address)\User -p Password cmd -accepteula` ?

Comment: I do it every time, just in case... probably once would be enough... so you're saying that with explorer you are able to connect to admin share? try on explorer: `\\IP_OF_REMOTE_MACHINE\ADMIN$` (you're giving admin user/pass, right?)

Comment: Hm, the command: `psexec \\(IP Address) -u User cmd -accepteula` works on our Windows 7 machines, but not our XP machines... Is there a certain way I have to run the commands for XP?

Comment: AFAIR, on Windows XP you need to setup something to make it work after lates patches... but I'm not really aware of what exactly has to be done... try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304040 , this may help aswell: http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-could-not-start_topic3698.html

Comment: I seem to recall that on XP you must run from an account with Administrator permission.

Comment: Also, does it matter that they are running Windows XPE? I've heard that the Home edition does not include some of the files needed to use PsTools, is it the same with Embedded?

Comment: As far as I know XPE doesn't support RPC execute at all... so it simply won't work on that system. But you can try this tool: `http://www.dameware.com/` (trial, not sure what is that free version) if it would work on NT based auth, then it should work on `psexec`

Comment: @FlashThunder Okay... I guess I'm going to have to find a work-around. Thanks for the help anyway. :)